# What is the best way to return variable size byte arrays and strings in C++?

Tags: c++, vector, c++17

I have a class that wraps C functions for reading and writing data using file descriptors

I'm currently stuck at `read` method.
I want to create a `read` method that wraps the C function  [`ssize_t read(int fd, void *buf, size_t count);`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html)

The function above uses `void *buf` as an output and returns the number of bytes written in the buffer.
I want to have a method `read` that would return a variable size object that would contain that data or `nullptr` if no data was read.

What is the best way to do that?

EDIT: I already have a `char array[4096]` that I use to read data. I just want to return them and also give the caller the ability to know the length of the data that I return.

The `char array[4096]` is a member of the class that wraps C `read`. The reason I use it is to store the data temporarily before return them to the caller. Every time I call the wrapper `read` the `char array` will ovewriten by design. An upper layer will be responsible for concatenate the data and construct messages. This upper layer is the one that needs to know how much data has arrived.

The size of the `char array[4096]` is randomly chosen. It could be very small but more calls would be needed.

The object that contains the member `char array` will always be global.

I use C++17

Should I use `std::vector` or `std::queue` ?

Comment: If the choice is between `std::vector` and `std::queue` I'd go for `std::vector`. You have more options with a `std::vector` than with a `std::queue`.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "variable size byte arrays" and "variable size object"s in C++. In C++ all objects have a specific type, and a specific size. Your question is unclear.

Comment: What are your considerations? If one is efficiency you probably want to avoid dynamic allocation. How is this going to be used? If you're reading an integer and three doubles the best interface may be different than if you're reading a 4K movie file.

Comment: You need to allocate the buffer and `read` writes to it. And you do need to allocate a certain size, before you do know how much `read` will write. How much are you going to read? What size of buffer to you allocate?

Comment: Use a vector. But add a second overload that works with a user-provided buffer (either with a pointer and size arguments, or `std::span<char>`, as the cool kids to it those days).

Comment: With your new clarification you should definitely return `std::span` (or I guess `string_view` if you don't have that yet). Both your suggestions force a copy.

Comment: @Useless Please post an answer.

Comment: Sidenote: I find it useful to only use `unsigned char` for bytes whenever possible. It helps me to keep them separate. It keeps me from accidentally forgetting it's not a string, or checking for a null char or other type errors.

Comment: @Useless I'll definitely check it out! thank you

Comment: IMHO, the *best* way to do this is with templates.  This allows you to have a generic `read` or data type specific `read` functions.

Comment: @Useless: If the `char array[4096]` they read into is a function local, `std::span`/`std::string_view` would not be the way to go (what with the array expiring when they return). If it's a global or local `static`, sure, views are fine, but that's begging for problems with reentrancy and threading. And if it is a global, there'd be no need to return it, which makes me suspicious that it's really an expiring stack local.

Comment: I would not use your temporary buffer that gets overwritten with each call. You may as well allocate a new object for every call so none of your returned data is invalidated. What type of data do you have? Is it text? Or is it binary? Is it a character encoding? I would think return something between either a `std::string` (for text) or a `std::vector<std::byte>` (for binary).

Comment: What is the signature of your wrapper function?

Comment: You may find `std::optional` useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> EDIT: I already have a `char array[4096]` that I use to read data. I just want to return them and also give the caller the ability to know the length of the data that I return.

Right, so the key information is that you don't want to copy that (or at least you don't want to force an additional copy).

Current preferred return type is `std::span`, but that's C++20 and you're still on 17.

Second preference is `std::string_view`. It'll work fine for binary data but may confuse people who expect it to be printable, not contain null terminators and so on.

Otherwise you can obviously return some struct or tuple with pointer & length (and possibly`errno`, which is otherwise discarded).

Returning something that might be `nullptr` is pretty much the *least* preferred option. Don't do it. It's actually harder to use correctly than the original C interface.

Comment: If I can do that with no additional copy that would be the best solution.

Comment: You should definitely confirm that `char array[4096]` is a global or local `static` before making this suggestion; the program will crash and burn if that array is a non-`static` local variable that expires when the function returns.

Comment: I had a struct with a pointer and a length as members and converted it to class with `std::vector` but I had to copy every byte into the vector.

Comment: @ShadowRanger `char array[4096]` is a member of the class. The object of the class is global.

Comment: @MrBit: You need to provide more of these details in the question, and explain why it's in the class; by having that single shared buffer, you're making your code non-reentrant and impossible to use in a thread-safe manner (because two `read`s at the same time would be writing to the same buffer), and using `std::span` or `std::string_view` to return a view of it extends the window for mistakes (call `read` twice in a row, no reentrancy or threads at all, and the return from the first call is invalid the moment you make the second call).

Comment: @ShadowRanger I provided more detail on that

Answer (score 2):

The general answer here is: Don't use mutable global state. It breaks reentrancy and threading. And don't compound the issue by trying to return views of mutable global state, which makes even sequential calls a problem.

Just allocate a per-call buffer and use that; if you want to allow the caller to provide a buffer, that's also acceptable. Examples would look like:

```
// Some class assumed to have an fd member for reading via the C API
class Reader
{
// Define member attributes, e.g. fd

public:
    std::string_view read(std::string& buf) {
        ssize_t numread = read(fd, buf.data(), buf.size());
        // Error checking if applicable, presumably handling negative return values
        // by raising exception
        return std::string_view(buf.data(), numread); // Guaranteed copy-elision
    }

    std::string read(size_t max_read) {
        std::string buf(max_read, '\0');  // Allocate appropriately sized buffer
        auto view = read(buf);  // Delegate to view-based API
        buf.resize(view.size());  // Resize to match amount actually read
        return buf;  // Likely (but not guaranteed) NRVO based copy-elision
    }
}
```

`std::string` and `std::string_view` could be replaced with `std::vector` and `std::span` of some type in C++20 if you preferred (`std::span` would allow receiving a `std::span` instead of `std::string&` in C++20, making the code more generic).

This provides the caller with multiple options:

1. Call `read` with an existing pre-sized `std::string` (maybe change to `std::span` for C++20) that the caller can reuse over and over
2. Call `read` with an explicit size and get a freshly allocated `std::string` with few if any no copies involved (NRVO will avoid copying the `std::string` being returned in most cases, though if the underlying `read` reads very little, the `resize` call might reallocate the underlying storage and trigger a copy of whatever real data exists)

For maximum efficiency, many callers calling this repeatedly would choose #1 (they'd just create a local `std::string` of a given size, pass it in by reference, then use the returned `std::string_view` to limit how much of the buffer they actually work with), but for simple one-off uses, option #2 is convenient.

Comment: @TedLyngmo: Ah, you're right. `std::span` could do the trick, but that's C++20 only. I guess only option is a mutable `std::string` reference? Or ugliness with pointers and available lengths. I've fixed it.

Comment: Thank you for your time! I'll take your advice!

Comment: Wouldn't returning `std::string` by value affect the performance?

Comment: @MrBit: Most modern C++ compilers with even the most basic optimization will do NRVO copy-elision; it'll be constructed directly into caller allocated memory, no copies, no moves. The cost is just the actual up-front allocation/zeroing, but return by value is actually the way you want to go here (trying to do `std::move` would inhibit NRVO).

Comment: Does GCC do that?

Comment: @MrBit: All the major compilers I'm aware of do it. It's got some rules to it (must return one specific object, not conditionally return one of multiple objects, can't return an argument, etc.), but NRVO has been a thing in some compilers since (IIRC) before the standard officially allowed for it (by explicitly saying it was okay to bypass copy/move constructors, even if they might have side-effects), and it's been used in most compilers, including all the big ones, for a decade or so now. [More on copy elision, mandatory and otherwise](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision).

Comment: Even when NRVO can't perform complete copy-elision (e.g. because the return value from a function is assigned to an existing object, not a newly declared one, so the existing object must be reassigned, not initialized from scratch), the compiler will typically implement it as constructing to a temp space then moving to the target space, and for `std::string`, that's just copying around a few pointers, not copying the data they point to.

Comment: That's impressive

Comment: Which exactly is the "mutable global state" here?

Comment: @MrBit: I'm referring to using a buffer in the global object that you return views of/references to (in an attempt to avoid copying data): "The object that contains the member char array will always be global." If it's global, then there is only one copy, no matter how many threads, or how many call sites want to use the `read` call; each new call to `read` would invalidate the results of any/all prior/concurrent `read`s, and there's no way to avoid it. Allowing callers to provide the buffer, or allocating per-call buffers, means multiple places can use `read` without conflict.

Answer (score 1):

You could use function overloading:

```
void read(int fileDescriptor, short int & variable)
{
    static_cast<void>(read(fileDescriptor, &variable, sizeof(variable));
}

void read(int fileDescriptor, int & variable)
{
    static_cast<void>(read(fileDescriptor, &variable, sizeof(variable));
}
```

You may want to also look into using templates.